# Why when using grouping_id with rollup the total will be level 3 instead of 2?

Tags: oracle, grouping-sets

Is there any logic behind the reason to why the total grouping when using rollup will be "lvl" 3?..

example:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 |
| id1 | 2 |
| id2 | 1 |
| id2 | 2 |
| id3 | 1 |
| id3 | 2 |

In cube method this is understandable as

- level 0 is the "basic values" (my own term)such as "col1-ID1","col2-id1", "col3-id1" etc..,
- level 1 will be the subtotal row of each basic value which means subtotal of ID1(1)+ID1(2) --> id1(3) for example.
- level 2 will be the total of each combination which means subtotal of 1's and subtotal of 2's , in this example: 1- subtotal will be 3 and 2-subtotal will be 6
- and level 3 will be the grand total of them all, in this example: 9

my explanation might not make any sense:) .. sorry

Is there any reason behind that skipping from lvl 0/1 straight to 3? or its just the way it is?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a query with the `ROLLUP`/`CUBE` expression that generates the output you are discussing.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: The grand total will be in the grouping set with the id the maximum value of the grouping set which is equal to 2<sup>(number of columns in the grouping set)</sup> - 1. Therefore, with 2 columns being cubed, the grand total is in 2<sup>2</sup>-1 = 3 and, with 3 columns being cubed, the grand total is in 2<sup>3</sup>-1 = 7.

---

Given the query:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS col1,
       LISTAGG(col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) AS col2,
       GROUPING_ID(col1, col2) AS grp
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY CUBE(col1, col2)
ORDER BY grp, col1, col2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2) AS
SELECT 'id1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'id1', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'id2', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'id2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'id3', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'id3', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 0 |
| id1 | 2 | 0 |
| id2 | 1 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 0 |
| id3 | 1 | 0 |
| id3 | 2 | 0 |
| id1,id1 | 1,2 | 1 |
| id2,id2 | 1,2 | 1 |
| id3,id3 | 1,2 | 1 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 1,1,1 | 2 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 2,2,2 | 2 |
| id1,id1,id2,id2,id3,id3 | 1,1,1,2,2,2 | 3 |

You can see that when `GROUPING_ID(col1, col2)` is:

0. The un-grouped value.
1. The value grouped by the first column in the grouping set (and there is one value for the first column and `N` values for the second column).
2. The value grouped by the second column in the grouping set (and there are `M` values for the first column and one value for the second column).
3. The value grouped by the both columns in the grouping set (and there are `M` values for the first column and `N` values for the second column giving `N*M` total values); which will give you the grand total.

---

If you had the sample data with 3 columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT t1.COLUMN_VALUE,
       t2.COLUMN_VALUE,
       t3.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('id1', 'id2', 'id3')) t1
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2)) t2
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(3, 4)) t3;
```

Then using `CUBE` across 3 columns:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(col1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) AS col1,
       LISTAGG(col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) AS col2,
       LISTAGG(col3, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col3) AS col3,
       GROUPING_ID(col1, col2, col3) AS grp
FROM   table2
GROUP BY CUBE(col1, col2, col3)
ORDER BY grp, col1, col2, col3
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| id1 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| id1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| id1 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| id2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| id2 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| id2 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| id3 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| id3 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| id3 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| id3 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| id1,id1 | 1,1 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id1,id1 | 2,2 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id2,id2 | 1,1 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id2,id2 | 2,2 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id3,id3 | 1,1 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id3,id3 | 2,2 | 3,4 | 1 |
| id1,id1 | 1,2 | 3,3 | 2 |
| id1,id1 | 1,2 | 4,4 | 2 |
| id2,id2 | 1,2 | 3,3 | 2 |
| id2,id2 | 1,2 | 4,4 | 2 |
| id3,id3 | 1,2 | 3,3 | 2 |
| id3,id3 | 1,2 | 4,4 | 2 |
| id1,id1,id1,id1 | 1,1,2,2 | 3,3,4,4 | 3 |
| id2,id2,id2,id2 | 1,1,2,2 | 3,3,4,4 | 3 |
| id3,id3,id3,id3 | 1,1,2,2 | 3,3,4,4 | 3 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 1,1,1 | 3,3,3 | 4 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 1,1,1 | 4,4,4 | 4 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 2,2,2 | 3,3,3 | 4 |
| id1,id2,id3 | 2,2,2 | 4,4,4 | 4 |
| id1,id1,id2,id2,id3,id3 | 1,1,1,1,1,1 | 3,3,3,4,4,4 | 5 |
| id1,id1,id2,id2,id3,id3 | 2,2,2,2,2,2 | 3,3,3,4,4,4 | 5 |
| id1,id1,id2,id2,id3,id3 | 1,1,1,2,2,2 | 3,3,3,3,3,3 | 6 |
| id1,id1,id2,id2,id3,id3 | 1,1,1,2,2,2 | 4,4,4,4,4,4 | 6 |
| id1,id1,id1,id1,id2,id2,id2,id2,id3,id3,id3,id3 | 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2 | 3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4 | 7 |

And will generate 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 levels (from 0 to 7) since there are all the possible combinations of grouping 3 columns and the grand-total will be in level 7; compared to 2<sup>2</sup> levels (0 to 3) when you are cubing 2 columns and the grand total is in level 3.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3_LOGG1-)

---

#### Update

> What I don't understand is why roll up is skipping level 2 straight to 3?

From the [`SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html):

> #### `ROLLUP`
>
> The `ROLLUP` operation in the `simple_grouping_clause` groups the selected rows based on the values of the first n, n-1, n-2, ... 0 expressions in the `GROUP BY` specification, and returns a single row of summary for each group.
>
> [...]
>
> #### CUBE
>
> The `CUBE` operation in the `simple_grouping_clause` groups the selected rows based on the values of all possible combinations of expressions in the specification. It returns a single row of summary information for each group.

`CUBE` generates all possible grouping sets; `ROLLUP` generates groups of the first 1 column then with the first 2 columns, 3 columns, ..., up to `n` columns which is the same as the `CUBE` when the grouping sets are restricted to the 2<sup>0</sup>-1, 2<sup>1</sup>-1, 2<sup>2</sup>-1, ..., 2<sup>n</sup>-1 (or more simply 0, 1, 3, 7, ... 2<sup>n</sup>-1).

This means that `ROLLUP` will skip the grouping set with id 2 as that is grouping only by the 2nd column and that is not "one of the first n, n-1, n-2, ... 0 expressions" in the `GROUP BY` specification.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HjDBa9VG)